# HiveQL query for a table of tweets

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hiveql

I'm trying to reproduce the results from [this article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/11/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop-part-3-querying-semi-structured-data-with-hive/): I have all the raw big data I need, and I've created the `tweets` table, but for some reason the "more complex query" results in a lot of MR jobs and ends with `No data available`.
I'm using Beeswax and its' query editor.

What can be the matter?

When run in terminal, the query results in

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 6.83 sec   HDFS Read: 274 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.96 sec   HDFS Read: 471 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 10 seconds 790 msec
OK
Time taken: 585.312 seconds
```

,where 0 HDFS writes looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, everyone: it turned out that I should have loaded data into a table before running any queries against it.